# Jcenter link to privately hosted repo

Tags: gradle, bintray, jcenter

I have posted several java libraries to Bintray, and then linked them to Jcenter. For the sake of argument, let's call one of the libraries  'my.private:repo'. This enables me to use the library in Gradle like this:

```
...
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
...
dependencies {
...
    implementation 'my.private:repo:1.0.0'
...
}
```

Excellent.

Now, a perhaps irrational fear of mine is that I will hit the bandwidth or storage limit for my Bintray repos, and so I will have to start paying to host the repos on Bintray (currently I have 18 repos on the open source plan). My question is whether it is possible to host the libraries somewhere else (like my own private server), and then have Jcenter simply do the redirection. I am fully aware that I COULD set up a private server and then do something like this...

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url ... }
}
```

But I really don't want to do this. I want to remove as much friction as possible from the build process...which means relying on a single server to do the redirection (like a DNS), and another server to do the actual hosting.

So is it possible to host the libraries myself, and simply have Jcenter do the redirection so that I can stick with the first code snippet?

Ideas?

As an aside, it seems like it would be smart to decouple the two things (redirection and hosting), but I understand that it is more profitable for Bintray to couple them since they can essentially force everybody who steps out of the memory or bandwidth limits to pay (which they couldn't do if they were simply do the redirection).

Answer (score -1):

I am not an expert on JCenter. However they could not possible offer such a feature for the billions of security concerns this would impose to them.

Imagine, you would be able to become a "backend repository" for JCenter (which would host maven artefacts on it's own). in case jcenter would not know a specific artefact on it's own, it would come and ask you about it. This would be a great vector for fraudsters to become a jcenter backend and publish "patched" libraries containing any sort of nasty code. In this case, JCenter would become distributor of modified (and possibly dangerous) artifacts from third parties.

The security threat would also exist if you would just ask for a redirect to a specific address. that server of yours could still become taken over by hackers and a modified jar could be published.

In both cases, it would be JCenter distributing possibly modified jar files with next to no control of the contents.

as an alternative - consider uploading your artefacts within the build job to a more durable maven repository - such as maven central.

Comment: I don't think that this is a valid concern. Jcenter could impose the constraint that only a single site can register to distribute a single package (they already enforce the constraint that two users cannot have packages with the same package name). Furthermore, they could force the sites to verify their legitamacy using GPG keys (which they use right now for uploading anyway). So everything seems to be in place for them to support this without security concerns.